# Item Editor form for list - use a lookup table for dropdown

Tags: list, lookup-column, dropdown

We have a list on SharePoint 2010 called "Policies". It contains a couple of dropdown boxes which point to custom columns. These columns get their data by going to List Settings > clicking on the column name > and then adding/editing items in the field labeled `Type each choice on a separate line:`. Can the column point to a lookup table (list) that the users can edit just like any other list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in several ways:

- Convert your existing choice field to an "open" choice field where you set allow 'fill-in' choices to "Yes" [image: allow fill in]
- Use Lookup in a different list (as you suggest)[image: lookup]
- Use a Managed Metadata field and select a taxonomy that is administered by selected Group Managers [image]
- Use a Managed Metadata field and select an open taxonomy (folksonomy) that end users can add to, by setting Allow 'Fill-in' choices.

Both Taxonomy options requires that you set up [Managed Metadata Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402.aspx) and define a Group and a Term Set that matches your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Anders, for providing all the options. The Managed MetaData option looks intriguing; haven't worked with it yet. The Lookup Column type best suits our needs; it's like a foreign key relationship. The "open" choice field will make it difficult to have a valid list of items, as the end user (with proper permissions) can add anything s/he wants.